# form validations in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating a form, i have gone through various websites where i found validation like below ,can someone explain what is the use of it.

```
      this.form = fbld.group({
        firstname: [''],
        lastname: ['', Validators.required],
        profilename: ['', Validators.required],
        email: ['', Validators.required],
        image: [''],
        phone: ['', phoneValidator],
        street: ['', Validators.required],
        country: [''],
    });
```

Comment: This is Data Driven form validation technique you can use in angular2. You can validate a form with `ngFormModel` in this technique. For details: http://blog.angular-university.io/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to read this [article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html) as it explains this very clearly. Perhaps you would be interested in this [one](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/21/template-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html) - personally I prefer last option as it covers most of the needs and is more readable.

UPD:

However, to take your example you should use it like this in your template:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <label>Firstname:</label>
  <input type="text" formControlName="firstname">

  <label>Lastname:</label>
  <input type="text" formControlName="lastname">

  <!-- Other inputs here ...-->

</form>
```

Comment: The essential parts should be included in the answer directly. Link-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

This is Importing fields which is written in the HTML page, 
and the ('', Validators.required) the first single Quotation is entering some data in UI part will save in b/w quotation

Answer (score 0):

Up to my understanding..

You have used reactive forms validations. Where it is useful is mainly at conditional validations.

Let us Assume.

UserRegistration Form:

```
this.form = fbld.group({
        firstname: [''],
        lastname: ['', Validators.required],
        profilename: ['', Validators.required],
        email: ['', Validators.required],
        image: [''],
        phone: ['', phoneValidator],
        street: ['', Validators.required],
        country: [''],
    });
```

EmployeeRegistration Form where street field is optional.

```
this.form = fbld.group({
            firstname: [''],
            lastname: ['', Validators.required],
            profilename: ['', Validators.required],
            email: ['', Validators.required],
            image: [''],
            phone: ['', phoneValidator],
            street: [''],
            country: [''],
        });
```

In above cases same view is used in different scenarios with out hard job.